# Is there a way for vba to recognize the function of x inside a cell as a function of x?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate determining the roots with Muller's Method, I don't want to jump the macros everytime i change functions.

Everytime I input a function at cell B2 it says, Error Overflow and doesn't recognize is as a function. Is there a way around this?

When calling the function on B2(e.g. the function is (exp(x)-sin(x), the code treats it as a whole thing and doesn't substitute the values of x into it,Therefore, instead of writing values for f(x0,x1,x2) it writes (exp(x)-sin(x) instead.

```
Function F(X)

F = Range("b2").Value


End Function


Sub muller()

        ea = 1
        x0 = Range("B4").Value
        x1 = Range("c4").Value
        x2 = Range("d4").Value
        i = 1
Do While ea > 0.0005

        ea = Abs((x2 - x1) / x2)
        fx0 = F(x0)
        fx1 = F(x1)
        fx2 = F(x2)

        Cells(8 + i, 2) = x0
        Cells(8 + i, 3) = x1
        Cells(8 + i, 4) = x2
        Cells(8 + i, 5) = fx0
        Cells(8 + i, 6) = fx1
        Cells(8 + i, 7) = fx2
         
        h0 = (x1 - x0)
        h1 = (x2 - x1)
        d0 = ((fx1 - fx0) / h0)
        d1 = ((fx2 - fx1) / h1)

        a = (d1 - d0) / (h1 + h0)
        b = (a * h1) + d1
        c = fx2
        
        If b < 0 Then
        x3 = x2 + (-2 * c) / (b - ((((a * h1) + d1) ^ (2)) - 4 * a * c) ^ 0.5)
        Else
        
        x3 = x2 + (-2 * c) / (b + ((((a * h1) + d1) ^ (2)) - 4 * a * c) ^ 0.5)
        End If
        
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x2
        x2 = x3
        
        Cells(8 + i, 1) = i
        Cells(8 + i, 8) = h0
        Cells(8 + i, 9) = h1
        Cells(8 + i, 10) = d0
        Cells(8 + i, 11) = d1
        Cells(8 + i, 12) = a
        Cells(8 + i, 13) = b
        Cells(8 + i, 14) = c
        Cells(8 + i, 15) = x3
        Cells(8 + i, 16) = ea
        
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    MsgBox " The root is " & x3, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `range` parameter to the function call.

That way you can use the function in the excel sheet and call with the range?

To do so add a 'Module' to the VBA project (i.e. add a module to your file)
As otherwise the function will not be available as Excel function.

Then cut and paste the functions in the newly added module.

It may be wise to use arrays and not individual variables in your case, I have amended accordingly, but the concept is the same.
I have also added a fail-safe exit (i.e. `And i < 1000`) to ensure the loop doesn't go into endless mode if it never reaches the threshold value.
I have also moved the initiation of fx to outside the loop, as in your example, you re-initiate fx every time the loop runs?

So that they look like this:

```
Private Function F(x)

    F = range("b2").Value

End Function

Public Function muller(rng As range) As Double
        
    Dim x(3) As Double
    Dim fx(2) As Double
    Dim h(1) As Double
    Dim d(1) As Double
    Dim iRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, ea As Double

    x(0) = rng(1, 1).Value 'range("B4").Value
    x(1) = rng(1, 2).Value 'range("c4").Value
    x(2) = rng(1, 3).Value 'range("d4").Value

    i = 1
    ea = Abs((x(2) - x(1)) / x(2))
    iRow = rng(1, 1).Row

    'fx(0) = F(x0) 
    'fx(1) = F(x1) 
    'fx(2) = F(x2) 
    
    Do While (ea > 0.0005 And i < 1000)

        ea = Abs((x(2) - x(1)) / x(2))

        fx(0) = F(x0) 'now inside the loop
        fx(1) = F(x1) 
        fx(2) = F(x2) 
           
        h(0) = (x(1) - x(0))
        h(1) = (x(2) - x(1))
        d(0) = ((fx(1) - fx(0)) / h(0))
        d(1) = ((fx(2) - fx(1)) / h(1))

        a = (d(1) - d(0)) / (h(1) + h(0))
        b = (a * h(1)) + d(1)
        c = fx(2)
    
        If b < 0 Then
            x(3) = x(2) + (-2 * c) / (b - ((((a * h(1)) + d(1)) ^ 2) - 4 * a * c) ^ 0.5)
        Else
            x(3) = x(2) + (-2 * c) / (b + ((((a * h(1)) + d(1)) ^ 2) - 4 * a * c) ^ 0.5)
        End If
    
        x(0) = x(1)
        x(1) = x(2)
        x(2) = x(3)
    
        i = i + 1
    
    Loop

    muller = x(3)
    'MsgBox " The root is " & x3, vbInformation

End Function
```

The function itself is not entirely clear to me, but the below two sequences don't make sense?

```
fx0 = F(x0)
fx1 = F(x1)
fx2 = F(x2)
```

As this will result that fx0 through fx2 will all have the value of 'B2' but alas.

The problem with this setup is that you cannot write data in the cell with the `function` as writing data would have to be a `sub`

You can now call the function as an Excel function i.e. if you type `=muller(B2:D2)`
It will use that range as its input.

** EDIT **

As you indicate in your reply, the function should be `Exp(x) - Sin(x)` then the function should be set as such? There is no need to call the value from the sheet?

```
Private Function F(x As Double) As Double

    F = Exp(x) - Sin(x)

End Function
```

I have moved the function call back into the loop as I presume it must be recalculated every iteration?

Comment: I see, your solution seems to be a bright one!

Thank you!

though, @mtholen .  When calling the function on B2(e.g. the function is (exp(x)-sin(x), the code treats it as a whole thing and doesn't substitute the values of x into it, how do i work around this? Therefore, instead of writing values for f(x0,x1,x2) it writes (exp(x)-sin(x) instead.

Comment: @AmerFauziTayuan
Not sure if I have understood your answer correctly, but if the function is as per your above comment, then set it as such? See my edited answer.